# Null check + dereference on the same line

Tags: java, c#, null-check

Are there any dangers in checking for null and dereferencing on the same line?

If `myObj` is in fact null, how would this code behave?

Are there differences in how different languages handle situations like these (ie C# vs Java)

For example, something like below

```
if(myObj != null && myObj.someProp == "Test")
{
  //...
}
```

Comment: I think it is safe because if `myObj` is null java won't bother with the rest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&&` is *short-circuiting* so if `myObj` is indeed null then the second condition will never be evaluated.

This behaviour is the same for both `C#` and `Java`.

Answer (score 0):

In your example the *if* condition expect a boolean value that is provided by the boolean operation *myObj != null && myObj.someProp == "Test"*.

When using the *&&* operator the left operand is checked first. If its value equals *true* then the right operand is checked as it's not possible to know its state in advance. But if its value equals *false* then no need to check the right operand as no matter the right condition state will be, the whole operation will result to *false*.
This is why it's safe.

But when using the *&* operator both operands are always checked. Your example would look as follows with the *&* operator:

```
if(myObj != null & myObj.someProp == "Test")
{
  //...
}
```

Doing so, when *myObj* variable is equals to *null* then the code above will fail. In this case your code won't be safe.

I hope this helps;